# How to use enum(rails 4.1)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I'm trying to use enum in my project.
but I don't know how to use it with simple_form input collection.
my code makes an error.
this is my enum definition in user.rb:

```
    enum role: [ :guest, :super_admin, :advertiser, :publisher, :account_manager]
```

and this is my view code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'devise/shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
       <%= f.input :name, required: true, autofocus: true%>
       <%= f.input :email, required: true %>
      <%= f.input :password, required: true, placeholder: "min. 6 characters",
                  input_html: {"parsley-minlength" => 6, "error-container" =>"#errorBlock"} %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true,
                  input_html: {"parsley-equalto" => "#user_password"} %>
      **<%= f.input :role, collection: User.roles %>**

    </div>
```

Comment: there are no. of gems available for using enum functionality in rails like gem 'enumerize' and https://github.com/adzap/active_enum or https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute ,check these out.

Answer (score 8):

When you do something like `Resource.roles` it will return a hash of keys and values like

```
{"guest"=>0, "super_admin"=>1, ...}
```

However, if you're using the `enum` in a form, by default it will simple display an integer field. Using `simple_form`, you can specify a collection set for the `enum` and it will return an array of the keys.

```
<%= f.input :role, collection: User.roles.keys %>
```

Since you pass in the `collection:` option, it will automatically change the input field to a select. However, you can specify this manually as well with `as: :select` or use check boxes.

Note that `User.roles.keys` will return

```
["guest", "super_admin", ... ]
```

This should fix the error message that you were receiving. Before, it was displaying the enum name and the selection was setting the integer value of the enum. When setting a value for an enum attribute, you actually specify the key name, not the integer value.

This is from the documentation http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html#method-i-inherited

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end

# conversation.update! status: 0
conversation.active!
conversation.active? # => true
conversation.status  # => "active"

# conversation.update! status: 1
conversation.archived!
conversation.archived? # => true
conversation.status    # => "archived"

# conversation.update! status: 1
conversation.status = "archived"

# conversation.update! status: nil
conversation.status = nil
conversation.status.nil? # => true
conversation.status      # => nil
```

Note where they set the value of the status `conversation.status = "archived"`, they set the key name of the enum and not the value 1. Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, User.roles will **not return an array** but will return a Hash like

```
{"guest"=>0, "super_admin"=>1, ...}
```

Also I don't know your migrations, but make sure you have the role field as integer in the database and not a string.

For more details on Rails enums refer the [official manual](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) and [this awesome article on enums by thoughtbot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/whats-new-in-edge-rails-active-record-enum)

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'enum_help'
```

And then execute:

```
$ bundle
```

In model

```
 enum role: [ :guest, :super_admin, :advertiser, :publisher, :account_manager]
```

In _form.html.erb using simple_form:

```
<%= f.input :role %>
```

For more information: https://github.com/zmbacker/enum_help